# Adding A Short Description To Product Archives

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to add a short description to my shop archives. Right now the only things showing are the image, title, price, & add to cart button.

Using "[Add shortened description under the product title in WooCommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073775/add-shortened-description-under-the-product-title-in-woocommerce-archive-pages/48074379#48074379)" answer code, I was able to get the short description to show.

This issue with this is for some reason it adds it above the product image, not between the title & price where I would like it. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->get_short_description() ) return;
    ?>
    <div itemprop="description">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description', 5);
```

The result: https://d.pr/free/i/kUiz7z

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'll try it later today and let you know the results. Thanks for the help

Comment: this worked for showing it but it is still above the product picture. I am using the code snippets plugin to add the code