# Add short description under the product title in WooCommerce archive pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

My site is https://outlet.ltd/deals. I tried to add a short description of the WooCommerce product to the achieve page grid (under product title) by following links but was not successful. Nothing shows up.

- [Add shortened description under the product title in WooCommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073775/add-shortened-description-under-the-product-title-in-woocommerce-archive-pages)
- [Adding A Short Description To Product Archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124689/adding-a-short-description-to-product-archives)

I'm using [REHub theme](https://themeforest.net/item/rehub-directory-multi-vendor-shop-coupon-affiliate-theme/7646339). Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','my_product_description');

function my_product_description() {

// get the global product obj

    global $product;

// get the global product obj

 $description = $product->get_short_description();

echo $description;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should add this to funtions.php, right?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your theme functions.php file.

```
// define the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title callback 
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title(  ) { 
    global $product;
    if( is_shop() ):
        echo $product->get_short_description();
    endif;
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 5 );
```

it works for me.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title() (previously declared in /home/outlet.ltd/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code:3) in /home/outlet.ltd/public_html/wp-content/themes/rehub-theme/functions.php on line 1797

Comment: You need to change the action function name action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title to my_action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title. So code will be like this: function my_action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title(  ) { 
    global $product;
    if( is_shop() ):
        echo $product->get_short_description();
    endif;
}; add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 5 );